# Как получить e-mail на почту своего домена?

Tags: php, email, centos, администрирование

Есть сайт, назовём его domen.com на сервере с centos 7.
Необходимо получить письмо со ссылкой активации от одного сервиса.
Каким образом это можно сделать? Вот отправили они мне e-mail на userdima@domen.com. Где это письмо искать?
В /var/spool/mail есть файл root, но там искомого письма не обнаруживается.

Никаких панелей управления на сервере нет, просто на чистый centos 7 установлены php-fpm, mariadb, bind и т.д. Письма с сервера через php отправляются нормально.

В var/named/domen.com.hosts есть строка:

```
@       IN      MX 10   domen.com.
```

может в ней что-то подправить нужно.
Сервер мой, работаю из-под root-а.
Подскажите как решить проблему.

Comment: [mta](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80) надо установить и настроить. или воспользоваться услугами какого-нибудь сервиса: от google, yandex, mail.ru, yahoo и т.п. // иногда хостинг-провайдер предоставляет такие услуги.

Comment: "Письма с сервера через php отправляются нормально." если с пхп отправляется значит сервер почтовой развернут нормально, тогда чего автор хочет????????

Comment: @ДенисКотляров "если с пхп отправляется значит сервер почтовой развернут нормально" - очень распространённое ошибочное утверждение.

Comment: "очень распространённое ошибочное утверждение." почемуже, чтобы отправлять почту с пхп мне требовалось разворачивать email сервер, ну как разворачивать учить его пересылать все запросы на яндекс.

Answer (score 1):

Вы ни слова не сказали про почтовый сервер, используете вы его или нет.

Письма никак не связаны с вашим сервером на centos.

В DNS-записях вашего домена есть (или должна быть) [MX-запись](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C_MX) о том, какой сервер обрабатывает почту для этого домена. На указанном сервере должен быть установлен почтовый сервис, чтобы обрабатывать письма. Разворачивать все это для простого получения писем нет абсолютно никакого смысла. Есть готовые решения.

Если бы у вас был хостинг - могли бы там воспользоваться услугой почтового сервиса, зачастую - бесплатно. Без хостинга - используйте [yandex.pdd](https://pdd.yandex.ru), к примеру. Подключить его не сложно, письма будете получать в yandex-ящике, по имени домена. Есть еще [google Apps for Work](https://apps.google.com/intx/ru/products/gmail/). Выбирайте, кто вам больше нравится.

Answer (score 0):

У вас вопрос делится на несколько частей.

Первую вы описали сами -- нужно корректно настроить DNS-записи. Минимальный комплект - это именно MX-записи, по-хорошему нужно ещё настроить SPF.

Вторая часть -- нужно настроить собственно почтовый сервер. Первый вариант -- поднять почтовый сервис прямо на этом сервере (например, postfix + dovecot - скажем [вот статья](https://habrahabr.ru/post/258279/)), второй -- использовать готовые сервисы, например, Яндекс:Почта для домена.

Третья часть -- вам нужно из php уметь обращаться к почтовому ящику и читать его содержимое, в php есть функции для работы с imap.